# Posts Table with Search and Sort WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, templates

I want to edit the WordPress plugin to show my products (in the database) as a table instead of my posts.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: I installed this plugin in my wordpress website. You have to simply write this shortcode [posts_data_table] and it will list your posts in a table.

Comment: Dipak, how can i as best post my code? It say me that it is so long